# Get position of svg element

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Why i can not get values of cx and cy ?
its print some array. i need only 2 values

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="red" id="cir"/>
</svg>

<script>
        console.log(document.getElementById("cir").cx);
        console.log(document.getElementById("cir").cy);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

The `cx` and `cy` properties are `SVGAnimatedLength` objects, not strings or numbers.

To get the actual value for `cx`, you need to do:

```
cx.baseVal.value
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="red" id="cir"/>
</svg>

<script>
        console.log(document.getElementById("cir").cx.baseVal.value);
        console.log(document.getElementById("cir").cy.baseVal.value);
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `console.log()` instead of `Console.log()`

`console` is defined by the browser, `Console` is not (JS, as most languages, is case-sensitive)

Comment: its print some array baseVal: SVGLength {unitType: 1, value: 100, valueInSpecifiedUnits: 100, valueAsString: "100"}__proto__: SVGAnimatedLength

Comment: its print some array. i need only 2 values